# RabbitMQ - parallel task consuming

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, symfony

I use RabbitMQ for sending a messages from symfony to nodeJs .I would say requires parallel processing.

I have a job per client that may take from 5 mins to 70 mins to complete depending on the amount of data to be processed for the given client. Client can post the job request randomly.

Let's assume that 5 clients post their job with the time required to complete respective job is as given below

```
client1 job - 65 mins
client2 job - 10 mins
client3 job - 5 mins
client4 job - 10 mins
client5 job - 20 mins
```

A normal queue has a problem as job of client1 is going to take 65 mins to complete and so client2 has to wait 75 mins (65 + 10) to complete a job that takes 10 mins.

I know that in RabbitMQ i can create many workers to handle this job, but depending on the time it takes for the job and the position of the job in the queue, it may take alot of time for a client to get their job completed.

So i am looking to create dynamic consumers per client. And each consumer does the job for every client individually.

Is this possible in Rabbitmq? If yes, how can this be achieved?

[image]

Comment: I'm not an expert on node, but I thought it allowed for asynchronous processing? Couldn't you have a process listening for RabbitMQ messages and then asynchronously process them?

Comment: @tr.am did you solve this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the part about [Fair dispatch](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-php.html) in the Rabbit MQ tutorials.

It shows you how to use `$channel->basic_qos(null, 1, null);` to handle only one job at a time. So you have a fair distribution of the messages.

Comment: Bless your soul, random internet stranger. I've faced a similar problem and this solution solved it for me!


In my case, I had a single producer and a single consumer with `noAck: true` and the consumer would just start multiple jobs in parallel and I needed them to be sequential.